# allow mails to one address only from local server

Tags: postfix

On my companies mail server there is a mail address everyone@example.org which sends a mail to every user which is useful for internal communication etc. I want to restrict this recipient to only allow mails from our mail server and reject any mail from outside to this address. What is the best way to do this in postfix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a pretty simple solution: Use [postfwd](http://postfwd.org/) (postfix firewall daemon).

Create a rule:

```
sender_domain!=example.org ; recipient==everyone@example.org ; action=REJECT everyone@example.org only allowed for example.org addresses
```

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to change the Mailadress of each mail to `everyone@` to `noreply@` so that these fast replies going straight into the void. You could do this through a header-check:

```
/^(To|Cc):.*everyone@your.tld/ REPLACE To:noreply@your.tld
```